# How to make checkered chess board pattern with CSS

Tags: css, reactjs

I am making a chess board in React and am having trouble making the checkered pattern. I tried using the `:nth()` property but can't logically figure out how to use it to acheive my desired result. My JSX code looks like this:

```html
import React from 'react';
import './Board.css';

const column = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];
const row = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

const Board = () => {
  let board = [];

  for (let i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (let j = 0; j < column.length; j++) {
      board.push(`${column[j]}${row[i]}`);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className='board-cont'>
      {board.map((sqr) => {
        return (
          <div className='board-sqr' id={sqr}>
            {' '}
            {sqr}{' '}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Board;
```

And here is the CSS:

```css
.board-cont {
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  background: rgb(119, 149, 86);

  height: 501px;
  width: 501px;

  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
}

.board-sqr {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.board-sqr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

This obviously doesn't work though because every other row is inverse on a chess board. With my current code, the board looks like this: [image]

Any CSS wizards have a nice elegant solution for me? [Here is the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/caseycling/chess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you'd call elegant but I've colored every piece manually by selecting odd and even on different rows. This gives you your chessboard. You can templatize this if you're using SASS or so but in pure CSS, I cannot think of a simpler way to do this. Maybe someone can provide a better way for you.

```
.board-sqr:nth-child(n + 1):nth-child(odd):nth-child(-n + 8),
.board-sqr:nth-child(n + 9):nth-child(even):nth-child(-n + 16),
.board-sqr:nth-child(n + 17):nth-child(odd):nth-child(-n + 24),
.board-sqr:nth-child(n + 25):nth-child(even):nth-child(-n + 32),
.board-sqr:nth-child(n + 33):nth-child(odd):nth-child(-n + 40),
.board-sqr:nth-child(n + 41):nth-child(even):nth-child(-n + 48),
.board-sqr:nth-child(n + 49):nth-child(odd):nth-child(-n + 56),
.board-sqr:nth-child(n + 57):nth-child(even):nth-child(-n + 64) {
  background: white;
}

.board-sqr:nth-child(n + 2):nth-child(even):nth-child(-n + 8),
.board-sqr:nth-child(n + 9):nth-child(odd):nth-child(-n + 16),
.board-sqr:nth-child(n + 17):nth-child(even):nth-child(-n + 24),
.board-sqr:nth-child(n + 25):nth-child(odd):nth-child(-n + 32),
.board-sqr:nth-child(n + 33):nth-child(even):nth-child(-n + 40),
.board-sqr:nth-child(n + 41):nth-child(odd):nth-child(-n + 48),
.board-sqr:nth-child(n + 49):nth-child(even):nth-child(-n + 56),
.board-sqr:nth-child(n + 57):nth-child(odd):nth-child(-n + 64) {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

[image]

In the code, I've used the psuedo classes in chain to control the start and end of their selection.

```
.board-sqr:nth-child(n + 1):nth-child(odd):nth-child(-n + 8)
```

This basically says select every odd element between 1 and 8.